# Server security experiment?

Tags: server, permissions

Okay, so I am in a university class where we are using a server.  Each student in the class has access to the server.  We all share it.  I can see their files and open them, and they likewise can see mine.

However, the other day I was telling my teacher that me and a friend were poking around on the server and trying to open each other's files and erase/write over what was saved.  However, we couldn't do it because of the restrictions on the server.

My teacher told me I could actually totally find a way to do this and screw other people over.

My first thought is a keylogger, but then I would get my teacher's password, and that just feels like a violation.

So I guess what I am asking is:  Is there a way to get into other users on the server's files and change stuff?

We each have a username and password for the shared server so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Since computer security fascinates me, and my teacher told me to think about, I'm all about the challenge?  Any insights?  Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of servers.  For instance, there are NFS fileservers, and some fileservers use windows, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess what I am asking is: Is there a way to get into other users
>   on the server's files and change stuff?

Of course there is. There is always a way in. Is there a timeout on the password attempts? If not, you could try a brute force or [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), there are thousands of programs designed to do something like this. For example, Cain and Abel is a popular one. You can also use cain for packet sniffing, if the files are stored on a remote server, you can possibly sniff for the other users' packets, and use a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack on their passwords(if encrypted)

Comment: Thanks for giving me some ideas.  Basically, we each have our own username and password, and I can open their files.  When I open the files, I can erase their text and hit save, but then when I reopen the edited file, none of my changes were really saved.

Comment: Oh, this is probably a stupid question, but I'm all about asking questions if I can learn something more.  So since I can see their file names, would it possible to create a file of the same name and try to transfer it over to their folder.  It should give me an option to overwrite their folder.  Would this replace that file with my file of the same name?

Comment: you could perhaps change the editing permissions of the folder, if you're an administrator, but since I'm assuming you're not, then that method may or may not work, I'm not entirely sure, but give it a shot!

Comment: I will definitely be giving this a shot.  Too bad I don't have access to the server right now.  I'm just trying to come up with some ideas right now.

Comment: If I answered your question, I'd appreciate it very much if you clicked the checkmark, thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry, I thought I'd already clicked the checkmark until I noticed I was still getting answers.  :)